# Getting the enum names in a list of string in Java

Tags: java, list, java-8, enums, java-stream

I have an Enum from which I would like to get the list of names in a string. However to do this, I'm, maintaining the values of the enum as well though they seem to be just duplicated names.

```
  public enum Forms {
   APPLICATION("APPLICATION"),
   VALIDATION("VALIDATION"),
   TARGETS("TARGETS");

   private final String value;

   Forms(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public static List<String> names() {
    return Stream.of(Forms.values())
            .map(Enum::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
}
```

As the names and the values are technically the same, I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this? I'll be using this list in multiple places, therefore I prefer fetching the list from the Enum class itself. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are not using `String value` anywhere. What's the point of that field?

Comment: Just remove the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the map to `Forms::toString`

```
   public static List < String > names() {
       return Stream.of(Forms.values())
           .map(Forms::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

And if you want to use the value (bad name for a variable):

```
   public static List < String > names() {
       return Stream.of(Forms.values())
           .map(Forms::getValue)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
   public String getValue() {
       return this.value;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Enum::name` returns the textual value of the enumeration as defined in the source code.  However, it's worth noting that the [JDK documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) suggests using `Enum::toString` instead, as it typically contains a more human-readable value (default implementation returns the same as the name method).  As f1sh pointed out, you're never using value anywhere, so the field is useless unless there is more code that you aren't showing us.

As an aside, you're reconstructing the list every single time you invoke `names`, I'd suggest storing it in a static final variable, like so:

```java
public static List<String> names() {
    return sNames;
}

private static final List<String> sNames = Collections.unmodifiableList(
      Stream.of(Forms.values())
         .map(Enum::name)
         .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: If you're going to export something of this sort, make it a constant field and make sure to make it unmodifiable.

Comment: Updated @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: The decision for either method depends on the purpose. If you want the strings for passing them to `EnumType.valueOf(String)` later on, `name()` is the right choice. If you want human readable names, `toString()` would be preferable.